# Is there an easy way to generate XML with method summary data?

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a tool that reflects a dll and executes methods dynamically.  However, I don't have any of the classes that can get invoked documented so the user can invoke the right method.

Is there a way I can generate an xml file based on the .CS file, something similar to the way the .NET Framework does it with their intellisense files?

Also, if there's a way to keep the summary data inside the dll and reflect that data out, I can do that too, but I'm pretty sure that summary data doesn't make the release build.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual Studio, have you considered using [GhostDoc](http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx)?

Either manually using it to generate XML document comments or in a macro to do the whole project/solution. There is a [thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/8a9a744c-b800-4bd0-a9d7-d7f2722f3aad/) on social.msdn which discusses doing this.

Comment: I am assuming you have access to the source of the dll you want to document as you say based on the .CS file.

Comment: GhostDoc is useful for commenting the code but it won't generate an XML file based on the C#.

Comment: Agreed but assuming John has the uncommented source, he can comment it with GhostDoc and build in VS which will produce the desired XML.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Sandcastle, this generates "MSDN" style docs from you code.

See: [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sandcastle/) and http://sandcastle.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=13873